# Refreshing value in a bound ComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I'm developing a WinForm app in C# (VS 2008).

I have a `DataGridView` bound to a `DataTable` (Fields) and one additional column - `ComboBoxColumn`. It is called RefFieldName and it is binded the same fieldsdatatable. It fills the column (RefFieldId) in this `DataGridView` with ID of a field chosen in the `ComboBox`.

Everything works except of displaying the name of field when my RefFieldId cell is already set. I need to display a name of the field with ID from RefFieldId in my `ComboBox` cell.

How do I refresh my `ComboBox` in this way?

Comment: What is teh datasource for you custom ComboBox? have you bound it to one of teh original columns in the dtaatable via DataPropertyName?

Comment: Yes! it is bounded to column RefFiedId in the table in my dataset. Of course I defined Name of field as DisplayMember and id of field as ValueMember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey!

I've found the solution, but it is not as elegant as I expected.

I've written a method that for each record checks all records in the table and looks for fit.     Then it updates the Name:

```
row.Cells["RefFieldName"].Value = refRow.Cells["FieldName"].Value;
```

Then  It is necessary to handle event DataError and create an empty method for that. If somebody knows better solution it would be great!

Regards, Kuba.